# VB.Net Framework 3.5 Access Database Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider not registered

Tags: vb.net

So i need to test a program with NET Framework 3.5 to have a Datagridview filled with data from Access Database. i have the code to fill like this :

```
Sub FillGrid()
    DBopen()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "data")
    DataGridViewCase.DataSource = ds.Tables("data")
    DBclose()
End Sub
```

DBopen()

```
Sub DBopen()
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="Filepath"; Jet OLEDB:Database Password="DBpassword")
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

when i run it i got an error saying:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

but everything worked fine with Framework 4.7.2 which i usually use.

Comment: The issue will be the target platform in the project properties.

Comment: Check what `Target Platform` and `Prefer 32-bit` are set to in the two Projects. These probably don't match. -- If you have the 32bit version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider installed, you can install the 64bit version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider. Or the other way around. You cannot have the 32bit and 64bit version of the same provider.